# Error in OrCAD: circuit too large

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, simulation, error, orcad

I am trying to simulate the elliptic filter in OrCAD and I am getting the error: circuit too large.

I have attached the screenshots of the circuit and netlist below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Read carefully the last line, in particular the letters in CAPS. If you're looking for a free SPICE simulator, there are plenty of other choices. All you have to do is dedicate a few minutes to search for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this carefully: -

[image]

Image extract from OP's image.

See also [this discussion on the Cadence PSpice forum](https://community.cadence.com/cadence_technology_forums/pcb-design/f/pcb-design/14273/problem-about-pspice-simulation).

[This thread](https://www.edaboard.com/threads/help-on-pspice-student-version.135256/) also says the same.

The op-amps you have used are based around several BJ transistors ("Q" devices) and, the total sum exceeds the limit imposed by the student version. There are fairly simple ways around this by modelling ideal op-amps in different ways (if you are interested).

Answer (score 0):

This is a limit in the software you use. There's a fixed number of electrical components maybe 30-40-60 and in your schematic more components than that is used, so it shows this error. Try to update your software.